# I want to send data into child screen in react native I added code

Tags: react-native

I want to send data into the child screen.
This is my code. I want to send data into allchilddtata.

```js
<View>
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name={COURSE_INTRODUCTION} component={Adddata} exampledata={example} />
      <Tab.Screen name={COURSE_VIDEO} component={LessonVideo} />
      <Tab.Screen name={DATA_ATTACHMENT} component={Lessonintro} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
</View>
```

Comment: Which version of react-navigation you are using? v4 or v5?

Comment: I use "react-native": "^0.62.2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass by callback instead of Direct Compnent

#### like this

```js
<View>
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Tab.Navigator>
// just pass it as a props in the component that is being return from callback
    <Tab.Screen name={COURSE_INTRODUCTION} component={()=><Adddata  exampledata={example}/>}   /> 
         <Tab.Screen name={COURSE_VIDEO} component={()=><LessonVideo exampledata={example}/>} />
         <Tab.Screen name={DATA_ATTACHMENT} component={()=><Lessonintro exampledata={example}/>} />
         </Tab.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
</View>
```

#### In Respective Child Components you can get the data by using

`this.props.exampledata` or `props.exampledata` Depending on what you are using either class component or stateless component respectively where you want to access the data.

Comment: how to get receive data in child screen?

Comment: Call this.props.exampledata or props.exampledata where you want the Example Data in the Child Component